# Embed react app with react router inside of another webpage

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to embed a react app inside of another non-react webpage. The react app uses react router for navigation. I have successfully rendered the react app, however the routes do not work correctly.

### Setup

- Parent page domain = test.com
- Embedded react app is using version `3.x` and `hashHistory`.
- When I use a route in the react app the router changes the URL to `test.com#/newPage`.

**This is the error**. I think it should be test.com/#/newPage instead of test.com#/newPage. How can I configure react router to use the correct url?

Comment: can you give details about how is react-router not working correctly?

Comment: Added some more details about my setup

Comment: Rewrote question to describe exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

React Router will change browser history which is global to overall page. There is no change configuration needed.